# What's 'comprehesion' mean in python 'list comprehension'

Tags: python

I know what list comprehension is, just want to know the name origin

It's hard to remember this widely used python concept without understanding the term.

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_comprehension "but the first use of the term "comprehension" for such constructs was in Rod Burstall and John Darlington's description of their functional programming language NPL from 1977." Might be a good place to start.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

List comprehensions existed in lots languages before Python. The first language which had them was SETL, but the first language to call them "list comprehensions" was NPL. After NPL, several functional languages included them, among those languages is Miranda, which was a very influential language, including for example building the basis for the design of Haskell.

So, part 1 of the answer is that NPL called them comprehensions, and everybody else after that did, too.

Now, NPL in turn called them list comprehensions in analogy to *set comprehensions* from math. Defining a set by defining its *properties* rather than listing its elements, is called *set comprehension*. An example of this is *set builder notation*:

```
{ n ∈ ℤ | (∃k ∈ ℤ)[2k = n] }
```

defines the set of even numbers.